# Linux Driver: mmap() kernel buffer to userspace without using nopage

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver

I'm implementing a Linux Device Driver for a data acquisition device which constantly streams data into a circular buffer I've allocated in the kernel (using `__get_free_pages()`).  The circular buffer (which is written to by PCIe hardware) resides in RAM, and I want userspace to be able to mmap() that RAM region so that userspace may read its contents.

According to LDD3:

> An interesting limitation of remap_pfn_range is that it gives access only to reserved pages and physical addresses above the top of physical memory. 
>   ...
>   Therefore, remap_pfn_range won’t allow you to remap conventional addresses, which include the ones you obtain by calling get_free_page. 
>   ...
>   The way to map real RAM to user space is to use `vm_ops->nopage` to deal with page faults one at a time.

In my case, I know exactly what addresses will need to be mapped to the given VMA locations for the entirety of the buffer at the moment `mmap()` is called, so why do I have to use the  `nopage()` approach of faulting in the pages one at a time as they're accessed?

**Why can't I just set up my VMA so that the entirety of my ring buffer is mapped into the user's address space immediately?  Is there a way to do this?**

I also expect that the userspace program will access my buffer sequentially, resulting in a performance hit when my `nopage()` function is invoked every time a page boundary is crossed.  **Does this cause a considerable performance hit in practice?** (My buffer is large, say 16 MB.)

(Notably, I've used `remap_pfn_range()` on memory returned from `__get_free_pages()` in one of my previous device drivers and never had any issues, but I may have just gotten lucky on that system.)

Comment: I'm confused. Are you asking how to use `mmap()` to *read* from your device to how to use it to *write* the data which your driver collected in a ring buffer so user space code can access it?

Comment: @AaronDigulla: Good point.  I've edited the question to clarify.  Thanks.

Comment: @BenVoigt:  Although this question is related, it is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @jeremytrimble: It's the same question, even if not all the existing answers are useful to you.  You should add your answer there.

Comment: It's not even close to a duplicate - the link doesn't even mention `get_free_pages`. This question is about the interaction of `get_free_pages` and `remap_pfn_range`.

Answer (score 3):

After a little more research, it looks like LDD3's statement is outdated, as per a (slightly more recent) LWN:

- http://lwn.net/Articles/162860/ -- "The evolution of driver page remapping"

*TL;DR:* In the past, drivers may have manually set `PG_reserved` on pages allocated by `kmalloc()`/`__get_free_pages()` and subsequently used `remap_pfn_range()`, *but now drivers should now use `vm_insert_page()` to do the equivalent thing.*

`vm_insert_page()` apparently only works on order-0 (single-page) allocations, so if you want to allocate N pages you'll have to call `vm_insert_page()` N times.

An example of this usage can be seen in the Firewire driver:  `drivers/firewire/core-iso.c`

Note how single pages are allocated by repeatedly calling `alloc_page()` in `fw_iso_buffer_alloc()`, and these pages are later mapped into a userspace VMA by repeatedly calling `vm_insert_page()` in `fw_iso_buffer_map_vma()`.  (fw_iso_buffer_map_vma() is called by the mmap handler in `drivers/firewire/core-cdev.c`.)

Comment: Didn't know about `PG_reserved`. However, you can call `remap_pfn_range` and lock down the pages if you have a `vm_area_struct` and set `VM_RESERVED` in `vm_flags`. There are several ways to get the memory first - `pci_alloc_consistent` > `virt_to_phys` > set `VM_RESERVED` > `remap_pfn_range`, for example.