# How to implement mmap() to obtain a scattered list of memory regions during runtime?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Typically when willing to let user mode code perform DMA, in device driver code, we would call `dma_alloc_coherent()` to pre-allocate a chunk of memory at load time (i.e. when loading the kernel module/driver); in other words, at boot time. Then in the `mmap()` implementation, we could use the kernel logical address obtained from `dma_alloc_coherent()` to get the page frame number and then pass it to `remap_pfn_range()`.

The above can be considered allocating the DMA buffer at boot time.

What if I would like to allocate the DMA buffer at runtime?

In other words, when user calls `mmap()`, the user passes in the size of the region, and when it comes to driver code, it will call `__get_free_pages()` or `alloc_pages()` to obtain contiguous pages, and then create and add the mapping to the page table.

When creating the mapping, I found one API that handles mapping more than 1 pages - `vm_map_pages()` (from [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71332950/how-to-create-vm-area-mapping-if-using-get-free-pages-with-order-greater-tha)).

My question is:

Since during runtime, requesting a large number of pages may fail; as a result, instead of only one contiguous chunk of memory, we may end up having a scattered list of memory regions. In such case, the user could access those regions using `readv()` or `writev()`.

However, in order to let user use `readv()` and `writev()`, the user has to know the list of virtual addresses of the start of those regions. How could we obtain those virtual addresses in kernel space?

The `vm_area_struct` structure has a field `vm_next` that points to another `vm_area_struct`. My current implementation is: for each list of pages we obtain (by `alloc_pages()`) we create a mapping using `vm_map_pages()`. However, by tracing the code of [`vm_map_pages()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/mm/memory.c#L1990), I did not find it creating new `vm_area_struct` and append it to the current `vm_area_struct`. That is why I am confused. If the linked list of `vm_area_struct` is 1, then how could we obtain the virtual addresses of those memory regions?

How could I obtain the user space's virtual addresses for each scattered mapping?

Comment: To avoid complicating the user space code, you could arrange for the buffer to appear contiguous in the process's virtual address space.

Comment: Memory allocated by `_get_free_pages` or `alloc_pages` (and using the `GFP_DMA` flag), is suitable for streaming DMA mappings but not consistent DMA mappings.

Comment: @IanAbbott: Thanks for your reply. According to this [reply by Linus](https://lkml.org/lkml/2006/3/16/170), at the bottom, he provides an example about ```__get_free_pages``` and ```vm_insert_page``` in a loop. I tested it in my ```mmap``` implementation in kernel module, but it failed even I tried to allocate 16 pages (the order I passed in is 4) and no matter the flag is ```GFP_DMA``` or ```GFP_KERNEL```. Since that reply is in 2006, may I know if you have any idea on whether the usage has changed since then?

Comment: Linus showed using `vm_insert_page` with a single page and with a compound page of order 4, but not with a non-compound allocation of order 4. Also, forget the `GFP_DMA` flag - that was my mistake!

Comment: @IanAbbott: Thanks! I called ```__get_free_pages``` with the same flags shown in the example - ```GFP_USER | __GFP_COMP```. I also tried ```GFP_KERNEL | __GFP_COMP```, but neither of them worked. The return values of each ```vm_insert_page``` are -14, i.e. ```-EFAULT```. In my opinion, this should not happen if my code is strictly the same as Linus's example. That is why I am really confused.